# Error using Pandas and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to transport csv data from `pandas` to database by `sqlalchemy`. Here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

file = path

csv_db = create_engine('sqlite:///csv_db.db')

chunksize = 100000

i=0; j=1;

for df in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize = chunksize, iterator = True):
    df.index += j
    i += 1
    df.to_sql('table', csv_db, if_exists='append')
    j = df.index[-1] + 1
```

But in the end I got an Error and the Python IDLE stop working. The Error says in the last line :

`Background on this error at : http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8`

I cannot copy the whole error log.

How to fix this? Do I need also to have the `sqlite` in the laptop?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you provide the traceback? The link only tells that there's some operational error, but not what it is.

Comment: @IljaEverilä When the error shows, the python IDLE hangs at the same time, unresponsive etc.

Comment: IDLE is well known to not handle displaying large amounts of text. Perhaps you can set up logging in your module and log to a file so that you can provide the traceback?